# Importing XMI in EA is throwing DAO.QueryDef Error

Tags: enterprise-architect

During the import of XMI into package in EA is throwing the error as shown in Image. What can be the reason for this error .How can this be resolved.

I am using EA 12.1
[image]

Answer (score 1):

What you are seeing is an internal error raised by the import process of Enterprise Architect.

There is really no way for us users to know why this happens, so you should report this as a [bug](http://www.sparxsystems.com/support/forms/bug_report.html) to Sparx Systems

Things you could try to work around this issue:

- If the xmi is created by EA: Run a project integrity check fixing all the errors on both the source as the target model and then try to export/import the xmi file again.
- Try generating smaller xmi files and importing them separately in order to isolate the problematic area.